# Migrating WordPress Multisite from Remote to localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I'm trying to migrate a WordPress Multisite setup from a remote server to localhost.  I'm using Mamp.

I've migrated the files and database.  I've used this tutorial on changes to the database: https://www.wpmayor.com/migrate-wordpress-multisite/

My sites are setup like this:

```
site.localhost
a.site.localhost
b.site.localhost
```

I can visit site.localhost and use site.localhost/wp-admin just fine.

Whenever I try to go to a.site.localhost or b.site.localhost I get the following error-

> Greetings Network Administrator! The network currently disallows registrations. To change or disable registration go to your Options page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you need to enable wildcard subdomains.  I found an answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57160/wp-multisite-development-with-mamp-pro-and-wildcard-subdomains-not-really-worki) that says you can point a new host subdomain to your current route that is already working.

> If you are using MAMP Pro you can simply just add another completely new host using your sub-domain and then just route it to the same place as your top domain.

Comment: Awesome!  I'm using MAMP Pro so I added another host and it worked right away. Thanks!